# Type Error during text lemmatization in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, text, lemmatization

I am working with text data and performing Pre-processing steps on it.

I am using SpaCy modeule to perform lemmatization on text. I have written code as below:

```
import spacy
import de_core_news_sm
nlp = de_core_news_sm.load()

def spacy_lemma_text(text):
    doc = nlp(text)
    tokens = [tok.lemma_.lower().strip() for tok in doc]
    tokens = ' '.join(tokens)
    return tokens

df['spacy_lemma_text'] = data['Text'].apply(spacy_lemma_text)
```

The code gives below error. I have tried many alternatives. 
I think it is related to pandas dataframe. Please help me solve error.

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object does not support item assignment
```

Comment: What it should be? I have also tried this code : ---->     df['lammatized_text'] = data['Text'].apply(lambda x: [y.lemma_ for y in  nlp(x)]). It gives the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea is apply solution only for non missing and no `None` values:

```
m = data['Text'].notna()
data.loc[m, 'spacy_lemma_text'] = data.loc[m, 'Text'].apply(spacy_lemma_text)
```

Comment: it gives the following error. AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'loc'

Comment: @user11603027 - I change `df` to `data` for both sides, can you check ?

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!